# Refreshing Structured Tables with VBA Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have two tables, one is just a list of locations and the other is a structured data table connected to a database via a MS Query query. In my structured data table, I have a parameter set up that pulls from the list of locations, each time a new location is fed into the parameter and data table is refreshed, I should get a new set of data based on the new location.

What I'm trying to build is a VBA loop that goes through each location, feeds the location to the data table via the parameter, and then refresh the data table to reflect the changes. Ultimately after each refresh, I want to save the new data table in it's own workbook, but I have to crawl before I can walk, so I'll settle for just solving the refresh issue.

Here's what I've tried:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim WS As Worksheet 
Dim CT As Variant
Dim MSG As String

Set WS = Sheets("Sheet1")

CT = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
For i = 2 To UBound(CT, 1)
    MSG = ""
    For J = 1 To UBound(CT, 2)
        Range("$D$2").Value = CT(i, J)

        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from Database").Refresh
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
          Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    Next J



Next i
End Sub
```

This is causing some of my data in the data table to flicker, but not change.

I also tried just refreshing the connection rather than the whole table, and that seems to refresh the connection just fine, but obviously isn't updating the data table. How do I get the table itself to refresh with each loop?

EDIT:

Based on some more tinkering, I've redone some of the code from above, but I'm still receiving some issues. The code loops through the lists of locations, and places the current location in cell $D$2 of the first worksheet (right next to the list of locations). From here the database query and the table are supposed to refresh, but the table only displays the refresh results when I break out of the VBA code by hitting escape. For example it will loop through the list, each iteration of the loop will place a new location in cell $D$2, with each iteration the data table should refresh based on that value in $D$2. What's happening is $D$2 is being fill with a new value with each loop, but the data table just stays blank, if I hit escape to stop the macro, the data table will populate with whatever value was last in $D$2. How would I get the data table to refresh after every loop?

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Dim CT As Variant
Dim MSG As String

Set WS = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WS2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
CT = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
For i = 2 To UBound(CT, 1)
    MSG = ""
    For J = 1 To UBound(CT, 2)
        WS.Range("$D$2").Value = CT(i, J)

    Exit For


    Next J

        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from Database").Refresh

          WS2.ListObjects(1).Refresh

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: how does the parameter get passed into the query when you refresh manually?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Each time I loop through the list of locations, It places the current location name in a cell next to the list table. From here the data table look at that cell for the parameter value. If I manually hit refresh, any location that is in that cell, will cause the data table to refresh accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that you do not set any specific references to the object parents when you work with them.

In particular you may think that this statement `Range("$D$2").Value = CT(i, J)` is acting on the cell next to your table, but its acting on whatever sheet is **Active** at the moment.

Try this code. I may have the specific assignments off a bit for your exact situation, but the overall concept should get you there if you make any needed adjustments.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim WS As Worksheet 
Dim WS2 as Worksheet
Dim CT As Variant

Set WS = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WS2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

CT = WS.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

For i = 2 To UBound(CT, 1)

    For J = 1 To UBound(CT, 2)

        With WS2
            .Range("$D$2").Value = CT(i, J)
            .ListObjects(1).Refresh
        End With

    Next J

Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have played around with the code some more, as well as added some elements you suggested, but I'm still getting some issues. Check my updated answer for more detail.